# Baking Simulations in Blender 2.91.2

Tags: smoke-simulation

I've just installed 2.91.2, and I can't find the "bake" button for smoke sims.  In previous versions, it was in Physics Properties under Settings.  The manual says it's now in the Cache List, but doesn't say how to get to it.  I don't see any baking options under the Cache tab.  Can someone tell me where I can find "bake"?  Thanks!

Comment: In the cache settings of your domain object, change the type from _Replay_ to _All_ - the bake button should appear.

Answer (score 0):

Baking is not supported on OptiX GPU rendering. Just switch back to Cuda, Go to Edit, Preferences, System > and wall la, Thank you.